# Fire Event from Service Running in Background

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am rather new to C# and parallel programming. I have following background task;

```
IsBusy = true;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        reportService.CreateReport();
    }).
ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    },
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Now, CreateReport in ReportService is does folowing:

```
private volatile Report report; 

public Report { get { return report; } }

CreateReport() 
{
   lock(this) {
       do some work computing result

       report = result
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => Report)
   }
}
```

`RaisePropetyChanged` should fire a `PropertyChanged` event in the context of the UI thread. However, ReportService should is not aware of running in background. Is there an elegant means for ReportService to detect that it is running in background and that is should mashall the PropertyChangedEvent to the UI Thread? How would this marshalling be implemented? Could I make use of `Application.Context.Dispatcher`?

Comment: Is this service an actual Windows Service?

Comment: No, it is just a c# class doing some computations and connects to a database.

Comment: I am not sure if that's possible, but I would consider encapsulating the call to `CreateReport()` and the notification/event firing inside the ReportService, which could be initiated on the UI thread, capture the context and thus be able to run the notification on the correct context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for all the valuable input, my current solution is as follows. I have implemented a `DispatcherService` which is injected into the base class of all my classes who need to notify `PropertyChanged`:

```
public class WPFUIDispatcherService : IDispatcherService
{
    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        // check if the calling thread is the ui thread 
        if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            // current thread is ui thread -> directly fire the event
            action.DynamicInvoke();
        }
        else
        {
            // current thread is not ui thread so marshall 
            // the event to the ui thread
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
        }
    }
}
```

The `NotifyPropertyChangedBase`, the key line is `dispatcher.Invoke( .. )`:

```
public class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IDispatcherService dispatcher;

    // inject dispatcher service by unity
    [Dependency]
    public IDispatcherService Dispatcher { set { dispatcher = value; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(
                          Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression
                   )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            MemberExpression memberExpression = 
                    propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression != null)
            {
                dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(
                                            memberExpression.Member.Name
                                      )
                           )
                );
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                     "RaisePropertyChanged event " +
                     "was not raised with a property: " + 
                     propertyExpression);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ReportService`:

```
public class ReportService : NotifyPropertyChangedBase, IReportService
{ 
    private volatile Report report; 

    public Report { get { return report; } }

    CreateReport() 
    {
       lock(this) {
           do some work computing result

           report = result
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => Report)
    }
}
```

The invocation of my service

```
IsBusy = true;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        reportService.CreateReport();
    }).
ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    },
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

`ReportService` can now transparently run in a background task or in foreground however the application is designed. In any case `RaisePropertyChanged` in combination with `WPFUIDispatcherService` guarantees that the event is fired within the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to run the continuation on the UI thread. In that case, can you not create a method called Notify in the reportService class

> Notify() 
>   {
>     RaisePropertyChanged(() => Report);
>   }

and call it from the continutation. This way it will be executed on the UI thread.

```
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    IsBusy = false;
    reportService.Notify();
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I find this to create too tight of coupling. I would favor a solution that uses the appropriate form of Invoke, because it preserves the encapsulation of the reportService

Comment: Fair enough. The other option is to either pass the UI SynchronizationContext to the ReportService class that caches it and uses it to execute the RaisePropertyChanged call OR refernce the PresentationFramework.dll in the ReportService class/dll and use the Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to execue the RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: Or I was thinking if the multithreading should be completely delegated to the report service implementation - see my comment to original question

Comment: Neerav, thanks for your suggestion but I go more with G. Stoynev with regard to the encapsulation issue. I do not want the consumers of the ReportService be responsible of fireing the event. However, I do not want to encapsulate the multithreading concern into the ReportService either. I see the background execution of the service as a concern of the specific application context. Here I have a WPF fat client consuming the service, however, the service could also be consumed by a web application where the the way to do background work is a different concern.

Answer (score 0):

My direct answer to your question would be to make use of the `Dispatcher`, but doesn't that make your solution specific to the UI framework?

I would also suggest slight redesign of your flow. The long-running aspect of the `CreateReport` routine is an internal detail of the ReportService. Why don't you move the multithreading/async details inside that class, like this:

```
public class ReportService
    {
        public event EventHandler NotifyReportGenerated;

        public Task CreateReportAsync()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    GenrateActualReport();
                }).
            ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (NotifyReportGenerated != null)
                        NotifyReportGenerated(this, new EventArgs());
                },
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

        private void GenrateActualReport()
        {
            var a = Task.Delay(10000);
            Task.WaitAll(a);
        }
    }
```

A quick test I did seems to be keeping the UI happy. This is how I "consumed" this in a Windows Forms solution:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private ReportService rpt = new ReportService();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            rpt.NotifyReportGenerated += rpt_NotifyReportGenerated;
            rpt.CreateReportAsync();
        }

        void rpt_NotifyReportGenerated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rpt.NotifyReportGenerated -= rpt_NotifyReportGenerated;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: G. Stoynev, thanks for your suggestion! I already considered your solution. However, I see the background execution of the service as a concern of the specific application context. A WPF app has to do it different than a web app. The ReportService itself should only be responsible for the business logic. Anyway, you are right with the Dispatcher problem inducing a dependency to the UI framework. What first comes to my mind is a framework service which encapsulates the Dispatcher problem an is injected by a DI container. This could be encapsulated in RaisePropertyChanged() of the base class.